# Magento2: redirect from Observer

Tags: redirect, magento2, observers

We have already know that **How to redirect from an Observer** for magento 1.x version.

but for **magento 2**,we does not know ***How to forcefully do redirection from an observer***.

I have done google ,but does not get any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i am writing some code for cart page redirecting.
In your module create a **events.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd"> 
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index">
        <observer name="my_predispatch_checkout_cart" instance="Namespace\Module\Observer\PredispatchCheckoutCart"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

In your observer file **yourmodule\Observer\PredispatchCheckoutCart.php**

```
<?php
    namespace Namespace\Module\Observer;
    use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

    class PredispatchCheckoutCart implements ObserverInterface{
        protected $_objectManager;

        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
            \Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart $_cartHelper
        ) {
            $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
            $this->_cartHelper = $_cartHelper;
        }

        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){
                //redirect to cart
                $redirectUrl = $this->_cartHelper->getCartUrl();
                $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($redirectUrl);

            }
    }
```

Comment: Why this answer was accepted? Its not working. Just check it from Listing page.

Comment: Wrong answer getting this Fatal error: Call to a member function getResponse() on null

Comment: **Note** : You cannot use this method (using `ResponseFactory`) if you observe `controller_action_postdispatch_*` events

Answer (score 7):

Yup, i have find **a solution by myself by doing a research**

If you want to do that then on `__construct()` function of *`your class observer`*,***you must inject two classes***.

- First, **`\Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory`** which  **responsible for
  redirection**,
- Another  class **`\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface`** which will make url
  for that redirection.
- Then create object for `ResponseFactory`  ,and using
  ***`setRedirect($YourUrl)->sendResponse();`*** redirect to your wished url.

### Observer

```
<?php
namespace [Vendor]\[modulename]\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class [YourClass] implements ObserverInterface {
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_url;
    public function __construct(
        ......
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url,
        ......
    ) {
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $url;
    }
    public function execute(Observer $observer) {
             $event = $observer->getEvent();
             $CustomRedirectionUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('[ModuleName]/[ModuleName]/[[Action]');
            $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($CustomRedirectionUrl)->sendResponse();
            /* die use for stop excaution */
             die();
    }
}
```

### Example:

Here i am write an example of that  redirection.

Basically `sales_quote_collect_totals_after` event,i was try to forcefully **redirect to contact us.**

**Here the observer code:**

> ```
> <?php
> namespace Devamit\Mgoto\Observer;
> use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
> use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
>
> class Challo implements ObserverInterface {
>     protected $_responseFactory;
>     protected $_url;
>
>     public function __construct(
>
>         \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
>         \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
>     ) {
>         $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
>         $this->_url = $url;
>     }
>   
>     public function execute(Observer $observer) {
>         $event = $observer->getEvent();
>         
>             $myfile = fopen("var/log/debug.log", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
>           fwrite($myfile, 'Amitber',true);
>           fclose($myfile);
>       // $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect('www.google.com')->sendResponse();
>            $customerBeforeAuthUrl = $this->_url->getUrl('contact/index/index');
>           $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($customerBeforeAuthUrl)->sendResponse();
>        die();
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: is the above code work for you, i tried your suggestion. it does not happens .

Comment: Yes,it has been working.Can u please share your code... i will check

Comment: die or exit is not expected as magneto2 rule

Comment: **Note** : You cannot use this method (using `ResponseFactory`) if you observe `controller_action_postdispatch_*` events

Comment: thankyou so much,i was missing die() and after using this my issue resolved....thankyou so much.

Answer (score 3):

injecting the `\Magento\Framework\App\ActionFlag $actionFlag` and `$this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);`is the way of forcing Magento to stop processing further events and redirect from an observer specially in the case of using predispatch event.

Here is the sample code

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{

    /** @var \Magento\Customer\Controller\Account\LoginPost\Interceptor $controller_action */
    $controller_action = $observer->getData( 'controller_action' );
    $parameters = $controller_action->getRequest()->getParams();
    $session = $this->customerSession;

    if({yourcondition}){


        // setting an action flag to stop processing further hierarchy
        $this->_actionFlag->set('', \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);



        /// redirecting back to its referred url
        $observer->getControllerAction()->getResponse()->setRedirect($this->_redirectInterface->getRefererUrl());
        $session->setCustomerFormData($parameters);

    }

    return $this;


}
```

Answer (score 2):

redirect to admin controller

```
  namespace sample\test\Observer;
  use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
  use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;


  class SendSecurityCode implements ObserverInterface {


protected $_responseFactory;
protected $_url;


public function __construct(         

    \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url

     ) {

          $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
          $this->_url = $url;
     }


public function execute(Observer $observer) {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $RedirectUrl= $this->_url->getUrl('welcome/code/index');
        $this->_responseFactory->create()->setRedirect($RedirectUrl)->sendResponse();

}
}
```